# Tranpose Col Values to Col Headers

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like below:

[image: table A]

And, I want the field values as col headers like below:
[image]

I tried using PIVOT function of bigQuery but that didn't work. Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot is the appropriate function to use in this case.  Try the following:

```
select *
from (select * except(field_id) from sample_data)
pivot (max(field_value) for field in ('name', 'age', 'gender', 'email', 'contact', 'address', 'state', 'city'))
```

It produces

[image]

Comment: that works. thanks, but how can we group by on id in case we have several id's.

Comment: just found out, pivot already performs the grouping.